# Dynamically update position on Angular-Google-Maps-Native

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

Using the Angular-Google-Maps-Native plugin, when I change the information in JavaScript, my map is not updating. I believe my problem is the $scope for the map, versus the controller I am running.

[image: Missing Title that is Hard Coded]

Sub Sample of HTML

```
<md-content flex id="content" class="md-whiteframe-z2">
    <div ng-init="coords={latitude: false, longitude: false}">
        <gm-map options="{center: [{{ScheduleCard.Latitude}}, {{ScheduleCard.Longtitude}}], zoom: 13, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}">
            <gm-marker options="{position: [{{ScheduleCard.Latitude}}, {{ScheduleCard.Longtitude}}], draggable: false}">
                <gm-infowindow options="{content: '{{ScheduleCard.VenueName}}'}"></gm-infowindow>
            </gm-marker>
        </gm-map>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Sample of JavaScript controller

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('ScheduleCtrl', ["$scope", ...
    function($scope, ...) {

//code here to load from Firebase

        $scope.ScheduleCard = {};
        $scope.ScheduleCard.VenueName = '';
        $scope.ScheduleCard.Latitude = 43.630;      // Initial Area 
        $scope.ScheduleCard.Longtitude = -79.699;

// reposition map based on this data        
        $scope.LoadScheduleCard = function(ScheduleInfo) {
            $scope.ScheduleCard.VenueName = ScheduleInfo.VenueName;
            $scope.ScheduleCard.Latitude = ScheduleInfo.Latitude;
            $scope.ScheduleCard.Longtitude = ScheduleInfo.Longtitude;
        };
```

Aditional side menu code for LoadScheduleCard()

```
<!-- Container #3 -->
<md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-z2">
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="schedule in Schedules" md-ink-ripple layout="row" layout-align="start center">
                <md-item-content>
                    <div class="inset" ng-click="LoadScheduleCard(schedule)">
                        <ng-md-icon icon="today"></ng-md-icon>
                        <b class="md-subhead">
                            {{schedule.GameDate | SLS_Date}} @ {{schedule.GameTime | SLS_Time:'hh:mm'}}<br />
                            <ng-md-icon icon="place"></ng-md-icon>
                            {{schedule.VenueName}}<br />
                            <ng-md-icon icon="games"></ng-md-icon>
                            {{schedule.HomeTeamName}} vs. {{schedule.AwayTeamName}}<br />
                            <ng-md-icon icon="thumb_up" ng-show="schedule.Wins > 0"></ng-md-icon>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="thumb_down" ng-show="schedule.Losses > 0"></ng-md-icon>
                            <ng-md-icon icon="thumbs_up_down" ng-show="schedule.Ties > 0"></ng-md-icon>
                        </b>
                    </div>
                </md-item-content>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
</md-sidenav>
```

Comment: where is `LoadScheduleCard()` being called?

Comment: On my side nav via a ng-click. Adding example code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the {{ }} in the options i guess
try:

```
<gm-map options="{center: [ScheduleCard.Latitude, ScheduleCard.Longtitude], zoom: 13, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}">
    <gm-marker options="{position: [ScheduleCard.Latitude, ScheduleCard.Longtitude], draggable: false}">
        <gm-infowindow options="{content: '{{ScheduleCard.VenueName}}'}"></gm-infowindow>
    </gm-marker>
</gm-map>
```